# How to add selected Tooltips in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am working on a project where the requirement is to show some selected Tooltip but by default Power BI has added the X and Y axis values to it.
**Is it possible to show only one of these axis as a Tooltip?**

Comment: As haoran zhang asked, what specific visualization are you referring to?

Comment: I am visualizing data on bar chart

Comment: OK, I'll have a look at it first thing in the morning

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't remove the axis values from the tooltip. However, you can make a [Report Page Tooltip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-tooltips) instead. That will allow you to put whatever content you want inside the tooltip. For example, you could add a couple Cards to show the information.